# Error: plugin execution not covered by life cycle configuration:org.codhaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.3:add-source

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to run a program that I've been given to include into a solution, but I have this error when I try `mvn :exec java`:

```
[ERROR] Could not find goal '' in plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4
.0 among available goals exec, help, java -> [Help 1]
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
 <groupId>fr.sesamvitale.agcl.testreleasecreator</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestReleaseCreator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>



<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>TestReleaseCreator</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>


    <jcomcore-version>1.7.1</jcomcore-version>

    <!-- versions des dépendances et plugins externes -->
    <log4j-version>1.2.15</log4j-version>
    <org.apache.cxf.version>2.5.2</org.apache.cxf.version>
    <geronimo-version>1.1.2</geronimo-version>
    <commons-io-version>2.0.1</commons-io-version>


    <slf4j-version>1.6.1</slf4j-version>
    <org.mockito>1.8.5</org.mockito>
    <jcom.http.version>1.6.0</jcom.http.version>
</properties>   

<dependencies>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.sesamvitale.jcom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcom-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jcomcore-version}</version>
<exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec</artifactId>
        <version>${geronimo-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-io-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>fr.sesamvitale.jcom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcom-http</artifactId>
        <version>${jcom.http.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>   
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${basedir}/target/generated/shared</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/schemas/ChangeService.wsdl</wsdl> 
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/generated/shared</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>${org.apache.cxf.version}</versionRange>

                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

> when i `try mvn :exec java` i have this error .

It's `mvn exec:java`

The error you are getting is that there is no action '' (empty string) because before the : there is nothing!

Official doc: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/